# How to define propTypes & contextTypes in same static block

Tags: reactjs

I am defining propTypes in static block of React Component till now, now I want to add contextTypes as well. Can I do that in same static block, or I have to do it in two different static blocks only. Which is the best way?

Below is my code snippet.

```
//All dependencies declared here..

    class FieldList extends React.Component {

        static propTypes = {
            data: React.PropTypes.object
        }

        static contextTypes = {
            intl: intlShape
        }

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="list">
                    // other code...
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default CustomFieldList;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "static block" ?

Comment: and by the way have you read the warnings about the Context API ? what big goal do you have that you think you need to use this API ?